# Difficulty to solve the exercise of Bisection method.

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, roots

Find an approximation to $ {25}^{\frac{1}{3}}$ correct to within $10^{-4}$ using the Bisection algorithm.

How to solve it?

Where are the function and interval here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most natural function is $f(x)=x^3-25$. You need an interval $[a,b]$ such that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have different signs. Take $a=0$ and $b=25$ for instance.

Comment: Is there any tricks to guess the function?

Comment: @tree, no general tricks. In this case, ${25}^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is by definition the number $t$ such that $t^3=25$, hence the function $f(x)=x^3-25$.

Comment: Or $(a,b)=(2,3)$.